# Are any{}, all{}, and none{} lazy operations in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am using a functional programming style to solve the Leetcode easy question, [Count the Number of Consistent Strings](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-the-number-of-consistent-strings/). The premise of this question is simple: count the amount of values for which the predicate of "all values are in another set" holds.

I was able to do this pretty concisely like so:

```
class Solution {
    fun countConsistentStrings(allowed: String, words: Array<String>): Int {
      val permitted = allowed.toSet()
      return words.count{it.all{it in permitted}}
    }
}
```

I know that Java streams are lazy, but have read Kotlin is only lazy when `asSequence` is used and are otherwise eager.

For reductions to a boolean based on a predicate using `any`, `none`, or `all`, it makes the most sense to me that this should be done lazily (e.g. a single `false` in `all` should evaluate the whole expression to `false` and stop evaluating the predicate for other elements).

Are these operations implemented this way, or are they still done eagerly like other operations in Kotlin. If so, there a way to do them lazily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those methods are not lazy.

First, bear in mind that there are multiple methods with each of those names: two defined on `Sequence`, two defined on each of thirteen types of array, two on `Map`, and one on `Iterable`. It's clear you're interested only in those defined on `Sequence`, as those other types don't support laziness.

So, let's look at the docs! The [docs for `Sequence.any()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/any.html), [for `Sequence.none()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/none.html), and [for `Sequence.all()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/all.html) methods all say:

> The operation is *terminal*.

To confirm what this means, the [docs for the `kotlin.sequences` package](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/), say:

> If the sequence operation returns another sequence, which is produced lazily, it's called *intermediate*, and otherwise the operation is *terminal*.

So those methods are *not* lazy; when executed, they cause the sequence to be evaluated as far as is needed to produce the required value. (However, they don't evaluate it any *further* than is needed, which may be what you're asking. After all, that's the point of using Sequences!)

(In fact, you can see from their types that there's no way they *could* be lazy: each of them returns a `Boolean` value, which is either true or false. To support lazy evaluation, they'd need to return a `Future` or similar object with a getter that could be called to produce a final result. But a `Boolean` already *is* that final result.)

Comment: "However, they don't evaluate it any further than is needed, which may be what you're asking"

I think I have some definitions that I need to review. This is what I am asking.

Comment: Since that's what you're asking, you should also note, the same functions on Iterable instead of Sequence also do not evaluate any further than is needed. See @broot's answer. The advantage with Sequence in certain cases is that is also skips intermediate operations for elements that don't need to be evaluated to determine the terminal result.

Answer (score 3):

I think you overinterpret what lazily and eagerly mean. Like "eagerly" means to always do everything in the most inefficient way possible.

Lazy collections (Streams API, sequences) try to postpone calculating their contents until necessary. On the other hand regular collections perform operations immediately when requested. But that doesn't mean if we ask a regular collection for its first element, it will iterate over all of them for no reason.

As a matter of fact, these functions are implemented in almost exactly the same way for both iterables and sequences. The difference is in other transformations and operators. Below is an example for `any()`:

```kotlin
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    if (this is Collection && isEmpty()) return false
    for (element in this) if (predicate(element)) return true
    return false
}

public inline fun <T> Sequence<T>.any(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    for (element in this) if (predicate(element)) return true
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs don't explicitly say, but this is easy enough to test.

```
class A : Iterable<String>, Iterator<String> {
  public override fun iterator(): Iterator<String> {
    return this
  }
  public override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
    return true
  }
  public override fun next(): String {
    return "test"
  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val a = A()
  println(a.any { x -> x == "test" })
  println(a.none { x -> x == "test" })
  println(a.all { x -> x != "test" })
}
```

Here, `A` is a silly iterable class that just produces `"test"` forever and never runs out. Then we use `any`, `none`, and `all` to check whether it produces `"test"` or not. It's an infinite iterable, so if any of these three functions wanted to try to exhaust it, the program would hang forever. But you can run this yourself, and you'll see a `true` and two `false`'s. The program terminates. So each of those three functions stopped when it found, respectively, a match, a non-match, and a non-match.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5BTsNADEX3c4pPV4kEHCAilcKODRtO4BbTjjAe5HGqVlXOHpI2FbQqiI0l2@99@z25RO37sBTKGQ0qPDkbLYQfXtyirua3x4knO02wD8Bnu5C4RNqwWXxlvLWKOIFFWV2XAGNvTeHrmIe@@yVoTfmZtz7mPKYkTHqhW8t/6Dq5x9Pn6sw5@@wgdyGM9AdFLchWuUJjRrvTx@VB3JCAUKMpyvHasHEZ8HvSHfbY4m4@lLqectGdU5qU/4GRyDd185PqQt9/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

In short, Sequences in Kotlin are somewhat similar to Java Streams in that they have many lazy functions that simply return another Sequence.

However, `all`, `any` and `none` are immediate regardless of whether you call them on a Sequence or an Iterable. You can tell they are not lazy because they return a Boolean instead of another Sequence, and in their documentation, they are described as *terminal*, which means they evaluate and iterate the Sequence immediately.